# Using for update with union

Tags: sql, oracle

How to use the select for update clause for locking the table with union.

is this possible

```
select * from table_a,table_b
where table_a.join_col=table_b.join_col
for update table_a.col1
union
select * from table_a
```

but this is not possible as we cannot use the for update with union.

can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle documentation claims:

*Restrictions on the FOR UPDATE Clause*
This clause is subject to the following restrictions:
You cannot specify this clause with the following other constructs: the DISTINCT operator, CURSOR expression, set operators, group_by_clause, or aggregate functions.

Comment: Then i want to lock the column table_a.col1, how we can avoid the update on this column from other program ?

Comment: @VijayNalawade - you can't lock a column.  You can lock set of rows `select ... for update` or a whole table `lock table`.

Comment: yes i want to lock the rows selected from select query for table_a in above query which have union clause.

Comment: @VijayNalawade - You can't do `select ... for update` if there is `union` inside.  Split it into two `select` statements.